# Comparar campos em dois conjuntos de dados

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Considerando dois conjuntos de dados lidos de arquivos do tipo `*.CSV` com o `Pandas`. Cada conjunto possui apenas um campo `CPF Favorecido`,em que se encontram milhões de registros. Cada conjunto de dados equivale a um mês.
Preciso descobrir quais registros (números de CPF) estão em um conjunto de dados mas não em outro.

O código está assim:

```
atual = pandas.read_csv(arquivo_atual, header=0, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', usecols=['CPF Favorecido'])  
seguinte = pandas.read_csv(arquivo_seguinte, header=0, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', usecols=['CPF Favorecido'])
```

Preciso apenas da contagem dos CPFs que aparecem no arquivo `atual` mas não estão no arquivo `seguinte` e vice-versa.

Existe alguma função que conte estes registros? Ou preciso construir um *loop* e fazer a comparação um a um?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira que conheço, usando pandas, ficaria assim:

```
atual.where(~atual['CPF Favorecido'].isin(seguinte['CPF Favorecido'])).count()
seguinte.where(~seguinte['CPF Favorecido'].isin(atual['CPF Favorecido'])).count()
```

Comment: Cara, eu não estava acertando a sintaxe deste comando! Tentei usar o "isin" por várias vezes e dava erro. 
Muto grato, problema resolvido!