# Diferenca entre tabelas, criterios

Tags: pandas

Tenho duas tabelas como a seguir:Quero obter os dados que estão na Tabela da esquerda e que não estão na da direita. Como as duas tabelas possuem um campo em comum, CPF, eu quero gerar uma outra tabela apenas com os CPFs que estão na tabela da esquerda, mas que não constam na da direita.

[image: Tabela Folha de Pagamento] trtreterter
[image: Tabela Plano de Saude]

Comment: Talvez fosse mais facil de entender se colocasses um exemplo da tabela que queres obter como resultado baseado nessas imagens, porque tal como está descrito é confuso. Vale a pena ver isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Não entendo o que a pergunta tem haver com [tag:pandas] (biblioteca python), poderia explicar a ligação da pergunta com isto? Quer, usando pandas, obter esses dados?

Comment: Como não entende? Sei q o pandas faz isso e muito bem, extraindo a diferenca entre as tabelas; já vi isso em video do youtube e nao to achando

Comment: Bem, eu fiz assim: nomeei o dataframe da esquerda como "novoPas" e o da direita como "novaFolha", e criei a variavel novoResultado, com o resultado da diferença dos dois. Ficou assim: novoResultado = novoPas - novaFolha. Ao rodar esse comando, tive o seguinte resultado:

Answer (score 0):

Bem, eu fiz assim: nomeei o dataframe da esquerda como "novoPas" e o da direita como "novaFolha", e criei a variavel novoResultado, com o resultado da diferença dos dois. Ficou assim: novoResultado = novoPas - novaFolha. Ao rodar esse comando, tive o seguinte resultado. Aparentemente, o que não esta como NAN é justamente o valor da diferença(o que não esta em uma planilha, mas está na outra). Eu fui conferindo, so pra ter certeza e o que aparece embaixo que nao seja NAN realmente não consta em uma das tabelas. É isso mesmo q eu quero, mas alguem pode me explicar por que?

```
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   3.145070e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   6.819145e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
...
```

Comment: Minha necessidade eh exatamente a desse cara; vou tentar fazer o q ele fez e retorno se deu certo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130338/comparar-campos-em-dois-conjuntos-de-dados?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Consegui o q o queria com essa solução q citei no link. Como eu queria q me retornasse a tabela da esquerda q não esta na direita, usei atual.where(~atual['CPF Favorecido'].isin(seguinte['CPF Favorecido'])).count()

Grato.